# How to display these values using PHP?

Tags: php

I want $amount to be displayed. But that's not happening.

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$message = "Thanks. We've got $amount from you.";
echo $message;
```

So now in the message displayed, $amount is not being displayed. Why?

Comment: Are you sure $_POST['amount'] isn't empty? Try just echoing that directly and see what you get.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/HJ9lHTHO . As long as `$_POST['amount']` is not empty, it will work.

Comment: Are you sure that $amount is set at all? Try a `echo $amount;`

Comment: @James The entire message is being displayed. Except amount

Comment: Are you working in pure php or using framework? Some of them clear $_POST array.

Comment: <input type="text" name="amount" value="<script>insert XSS here</script>" />

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably that the value of $_POST['amount'] is not set. Remember that the $_POST array will only contain elements submitted via a  on a page. Elements you pass in this manner: page.php?amount=2.99 will only exist in the $_GET and $_REQUEST superglobals. The $_REQUEST array is a merger of the $_GET and $_POST arrays. I would suggest adding basic validation or at least a default value.

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'] ? $_POST['amount'] : 0; //sets default to 0 if nothing was passed
$message = "Thanks. We've got $amount from you.";
echo $message;
```

OR:

```
$message = $_POST['amount'] ? "Thanks. We've got $_POST[amount] from you." : "Sorry, you didn't enter an amount."; //changes the message if no value was passed, otherwise uses your approach but gets the value directly from $_POST
echo $message;
```